# Is there any way to use indices which contains no query results as a statistical comparison background in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, logstash

I could find the criteria that Elasticsearch's **significant_terms** aggregations use.
I mean, *background set used for statistical comparisons is the index or indices from which the results were gathered.*

However, I want to use daily created Logstash index for significant terms aggregation.

Here is the problem I've faced.

If I use a filtered query containing a filter like below, it **ignores all logstash indices except for "logstash-2014.12.10".**

```
{
    "range":{
        "@timestamp":{
            "from":"2014-12-10T15:00:00.000+00:00",
            "to":"2014-12-10T18:00:00.000+00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to **use all indices that are daily created by Logstash** as the background documents of a **significant_terms aggregation** like below?

```
"aggregations": {
    "agg_by_remote_ip": {
        "significant_terms": {
            "field": "remote_ip"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about operations from Kibana ?

Comment: @VineethMohan No. I'm not talking about operations from Kibana. It is just about for general query.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query over multiple indices in the first place (note the `logstash-*` part of the GET request):

```
GET /logstash-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "from": "2014-12-10T15:00:00.000+00:00",
        "to": "2014-12-10T18:00:00.000+00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "agg_by_remote_ip": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "remote_ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei Stefan. However, my logstash indices are created daily as a different indices such as logstash-2014.11.01. It means that the query results only gettered from index logstash-2014.12.10 so the background does not reflect other indices. You can see what I mentioned about from here (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html#_single_set_analysis).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.